# Asynchronous Webservice Integration - Callback approach

Tags: c#, web-services

I have my webservice Webservice A that calls 3rd party Webservice B asynchronously. 
Webservice B can succeed or fail. It calls back A with success or fail information.
what is the best practice in this case? Create 2 callback endpoints in A (success and fail) or just one callback that can handle both sucess and error scenarios.

thanks,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go with a single callback I have found it to be simpler and it best matches my requirements (Since success and error callback would be very similar). Also I have noticed that having a single callback makes it cleaner to handle partial successes.